# Redirecting with <rewrite> in web.config

Tags: c#, .net, iis

I'm working on redirecting a URL to a new destination URL with the below `web.config` configuration but it is not working as expected, during the page load,

```
<rewrite>
    <rules>
        <rule name="Benefits to maxxia redirect" stopProcessing="true">
            <match url="http://website1.com/page/calculate" />
            <action type="Redirect" url="https://website2.com/page/package" />
        </rule>
    </rules>
</rewrite>
```

Please let me know what am I missing here.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The `match` URL is a regular expression that matches only the *path* of the URL, not including the domain name or protocol.

```
<rewrite>
    <rules>
        <rule name="Benefits to maxxia redirect" stopProcessing="true">
            <match url="^page/calculate" />
            <action type="Redirect" url="https://website2.com/page/package" />
        </rule>
    </rules>
</rewrite>
```

The `Redirect` URL on the other hand can be either absolute or relative, so your example is fine.

It is possible to use conditions to match the domain name or protocol part of the URL as [shown in this post](https://blogs.technet.microsoft.com/dawiese/2016/06/07/redirect-from-http-to-https-using-the-iis-url-rewrite-module/). For example, to redirect `http://authoring.mjleague.com.au/calculator` to `http://iotg.mjleague.com.au/calculator`:

```
<rewrite>
    <rules>
        <rule name="Calculator redirect" stopProcessing="true">
            <match url="^calculator" />
            <conditions>
                <add input="{HTTP_HOST}" pattern="authoring.mjleague.com.au" />
            </conditions>
            <action type="Redirect" url="http://iotg.mjleague.com.au/calculator" />
        </rule>
    </rules>
</rewrite>
```

Reference:

- [Creating Rewrite Rules for the URL Rewrite Module](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/iis/extensions/url-rewrite-module/creating-rewrite-rules-for-the-url-rewrite-module#creating-a-redirect-rule)

Comment: Thank you @NightOwl888.

I need to redirect my URL, "http://authoring.mjleague.com.au/calculator" to "http://iotg.mjleague.com.au/calculator"

There is also one more domain configured here, (i.e) "http://authoring.jpleague.com.au/calculator"

Both the authoring instances, are configured in the same website and i dont want to apply my redirect for the second URL.

Please let me know how to handle this.